# Show on user profile page the commissions he is connected to

Tags: templating, matrix, users, fieldtypes, relatedto

I have a commissions section in where we have a matrix field where we add the user (from craft.users) and the function of the user.

A user can be in more that one commissions.

On the user profile page, we want to show besides some personal information, all the commissions in which he is active.

For a single relation field (user type field), we have no problem, but I can't get it working with this matrix field.

Matrix field info:

Section: `commissionmembers`
Blocktype: `members`
 
Fields: `member` (fieldtype users)
        `function` (plain text)

This is a working example with a Users field

```
    {% for user in craft.users.id( craft.request.lastSegment ).limit(1) %}
    {% set commissions = craft.entries.section('commissions').relatedTo(user) %}
        {% for commission in commissions %}
            {{ commission.title }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Hope you can point me in the right direction how to get it working with the matrix field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’d need to query for all Matrix Blocks the user is related to using a Matrix Block ElementCriteriaModel. Unfortunatelly this is not possible from the template level by default, you need to either install the plugin [Low Blocks](https://github.com/low/lowblocks), or write some some lines of PHP in a custom plugin.

Here’s how you would have to set the params for the Low Blocks function:

```
{% set userId = craft.request.lastSegment %}
{% set user = craft.users.id(userId).first() %}

{% if not user %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}

{% set matrixField = craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('commissionmembers') %}

{% set blocks = craft.lowblocks.blocks.fieldId(matrixField.id).type('members').relatedTo({
    targetElement: userId,
    field: 'member',
}) %}

{% for block in blocks %}
    {% set commission = block.getOwner() %}

    {{ commission.title }}
    {{ block.function }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hey Carl, thank you so much for your help, it's working perfectly. However there was one thing I had to let out, and that is in the relatedTo, field: 'member'. With only the targetElement: userId it works perfectly.